# Como utilizar .directive, modularização e divisão de camadas? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, modularização

**OBS: Até entendi o tudo, o problema é que não consigo fazer com esse código as informações que me passaram, tipo nada. E quando faço não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor??**

Olá, eu estou com um sério problema em entender como funcionam esssas coisas citadas em um texto. Gostaria de criar uma .directive, fazer a modularizarão fazendo parte do código ser utilizada em serviços e efetuar a divisão de camadas nesse código. Estou começando agora a aprender então estou tendo muita dificuldade nessa parte do processo de criação Angular.

```js
angular.module('TarefApp', []);

// Code goes here
angular.module('TarefApp')

.controller('TarefasController', function($scope) {
  $scope.categorias = [];
  $scope.tarefas = [];
  $scope.categoriaTarefa = {
    tarefa: {}
  };

  $scope.addTarefa = function(tarefa) {
    if (!$scope.categoriaSelecionada) {
      alert("Selecione uma categoria!")
      return;
    }

    var c = $scope.categoriaSelecionada;

    if (!$scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c])
      $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];
    else {
      var itemDuplicado = false;
      angular.forEach($scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c], function(item, index) {
        itemDuplicado = (item.nome === tarefa.nome);
        if (itemDuplicado) {
          alert("Tarefa para categoria já existe!");
          return false;
        }
      });
    }

    if (!itemDuplicado) {
      $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tarefa);
      $scope.tarefa = {};
    }
  };

  $scope.delTarefas = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.categorias, function(item) {
      var c = item.nome;
      var oldTarefas = $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c];
      $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];

      angular.forEach(oldTarefas, function(tar) {
        if (!tar.selecionado) $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tar);
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.addCategoria = function(categoria) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categorias.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.categorias[i].nome === categoria.nome) {
        alert("A categoria já existe!");
        return;
      }
    }
    $scope.categorias.push(angular.copy(categoria));
    delete $scope.categoria;
  };
});
```

```css
        .container {
          margin-top: 2%;
        }
        .apgfiltro {
          margin-top: 5%;
          margin-bottom: 2.9%;
        }
        a:hover {
          text-decoration: none !important;
        }
        .done-true {
          text-decoration: line-through;
          color: #ccc;
        }
        .col-xs-9.edit {
          margin-top: 3%;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="TarefApp">
<head>
<!-- Angular.js minificado  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Angular.js minificado  -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controller/TarefasController.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="div-container" class="container ng-scope" ng-controller="TarefasController">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Categoria -->
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h4>Adicionar Categoria</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-form">
                        <form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="categoria.nome">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-click="addCategoria(categoria)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!categoria.nome" disabled="disabled">Adicionar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Fim Adicionar Categoria -->
                    <!-- Ínicio Adicionar Tarefa -->
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h4>Adicionar Tarefa</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-form">
                        <form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="tarefa.nome">
                                <br>
                                <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-options="item.nome as item.nome for item in categorias" ng-model="categoriaSelecionada">

                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-click="addTarefa(tarefa)" ng-model="infoIgual" ng-disabled="!tarefa.nome" disabled="disabled">Adicionar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Fim Adicionar Tarefa -->
                </div>

                <!-- Categorias + Tarefas -->
                <div class="col-xs-9 edit">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="delTarefas()">Apagar tarefas selecionadas</button>
                    <div ng-repeat="categoria in categorias">
                        <h4 ng-model="categoria.selecionado">{{categoria.nome}}</h4>
                        <div ng-repeat="tarefa in categoriaTarefa.tarefa[categoria.nome]">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tarefa.selecionado" ng-click="tarefaFeita()">
                            <span class="done-{{tarefa.selecionado}}">{{tarefa.nome}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Você quer muita coisa em uma única pergunta, nesta caso, eu recomendo que você faça o curso até a fase gratuita que o próprio AngularJS oferece [ http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/ ] , com ele você terá toda a base necessária para começar a criar cada um desses elementos.

Comment: Para mais informações, consulte a documentação: https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumidamente, vou explicar como funciona as diretivas.

1) para criar uma diretiva:

```
app.directive("nomeDaDiretiva", function () {
   //seu método 
});
```

2) para criar uma diretiva modulada:

```
angular.module('NomeDoModulo', [])
.directive("nomeDaDiretiva", function () {
   //seu método 
});
```

3) O que acontece é que apontamos o modulo para uma variável:

```
var app = angular.module('NomeDoModulo', []);
```

4) Então criamos uma diretiva:

```
app.directive("nomeDaDiretiva", function () {
   //seu método 
});
```

5) No módulo temos que passar os elementos que serão usados na aplicação, conforme coloquei `ngResource`, `ngRoute`:

```
var app = angular.module('NomeDoModulo', ['ngResource','ngRoute']);
```

6) As diretivas contém algumas restrições que podem ser definidas:

> **E** - Diretiva restrita ao elemento
>  
>        **A** - Diretiva restrita ao atributo do elemento
>  
>        **C** - Diretiva restrita a classe do elemento
>  
>        **M** - Diretiva restrita ao comentário do elemento

Aqui tem um exemplo de diretiva (observe que neste exemplo, contém a restrição EAC (em conjunto) e está modularizado: **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1cyxoytv/**

A diretiva terá um retorno, e nele podem conter os seguintes parâmetros
restrição (restrict), layout (template), método em si (link) e substituição (replace), este receberá um booleano (true ou false).

Também pode conter parametrização do escopo (escope):

```
angular.module('MeuSistema', [])
.directive('DadosUsuario', function () {    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
           nome:'@',
           email:'@',
           cidade:'@'
        },
        template:'<div></div>',
        link: function(scope,element, attributes) {

            element[0].innerHTML =  'Os dados do usuário são:<br>'
             + 'Nome: ' + scope.nome + '<br>'
             + 'Email: ' + scope.email + '<br>'
             + 'Cidade: ' + scope.cidade;

        },
        replace: true
    };
}) //o correto é separar isso em um arquivo só do seu controller em uma pasta "controllers"
.controller('ExibirDados', function() {

  $scope.nome = "Larissa Mourullo";
  $scope.email = "seuemail@gmail.com";
  $scope.cidade = "São Paulo";

});
```

E no HTML:

```
<html ng-app="MeuSistema">
 <title>Exemplo</title>
 <body ng-controller="ExibirDados as dados">

<dados-usuario nome="{{dados.nome}}"
               email="{{dados.email}}"
               cidade="{{dados.cidade}}">
</dados-usuario>

<script src="/directives/dados_usuario.js"></script>
<script src="/controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá:

Antes de mais nada você precisa entender o que é um controlador, um serviço e uma diretiva no angular

**Controlador (Controller)**

Entenda item como sendo um controlador dos componentes que estão em tela. Em outras palavras, aqui vão ficar todas as rotinas que envolvem interação usuário com a página HTML em sí. Além disso também partem daqui as requisições a outros componentes como por exemplo o serviço.

**Serviço (Service)**

Esse é o cara responsável por compartilhar recursos entre os controladores e também aqui geralmente ficam as rotinas que envolvem as chamadas http. É comum o pessoal usar esse cara para efetuar chamadas rest por exemplo. Desse modo você tem um serviço de pessoa por exemplo que pode incluir, alterar, excluir um pessoa.

**Serviço Genérico**

```
App.factory("$comum", function($http, $q, $injector) {
    function ajax(url, parametros, metodo) {
        var requisicao = $http({
            method: metodo,
            url: url,
            data:parametros
        });

        var promessa = requisicao.then(
            function(resposta) {
                return(resposta.data);
            },
            function(resposta) {
                return($q.reject("Something went wrong"));
            }
        );
        return promessa;
    }
    return({
        ajax:ajax
    });
});
```

**Serviço Histórico Venda**

```
App.factory("$historicovenda", function($comum) {
    var historico;
    return {
        buscar : function(filtro) {
            var promessa = $comum.ajax("/fusion/services/roi/history/search", filtro, "POST");
            promessa.then(function(req) {  
                historico = req;
            })
            return promessa;
        },
        cache : function() {
            return historico;
        }
    };
});
```

**Controlador Histórico Venda**

```
App.controller("HistoricoVendaController", function($scope, $historicovenda) {
    $scope.buscar = function(regerar) {
        var filtro = "1";
        $historicovenda.buscar(filtro).then(function(req){
            console.log(req)
        });
    };
});
```

**E agora vamos a sua pergunta:**

**Divisão de camadas**

A divisão em camadas é justamente separar as responsabilidades de cada um. Um exemplo prático: Você tem um cadastro de pessoa, nesse caso podemos dividir a rotina em dois componentes. Um controlador (*camada 1*) responsável por executar a ação quando o usuário clicar no botão salvar e validar os dados. Além disso esse componente também irá compilar o objeto a ser salvo e em seguida irá passar a bola para o serviço (*camada 2*) que irá efetuar a chamada http para efetivar o usuário no banco de dados. Nesse caso temos duas camadas com baixo acoplamento. Caso necessite consultar uma pessoa em outro controlador pode usar mesmo serviço. E ai está a sacada de separar as responsabilidades, você pode compartilhar o recursos.

**Diretiva (Directive)**

A diretiva é utilizada quando você quer determinar um comportamento em determinado elemento HTML. Também pode ser utilizado para você criar suas próprias tags. Existem muitas bibliotecas no angular que fazem o uso de tal elemento para dar um comportamento especifico. Exemplo:

**No Js:**

```
angular.module('App', [])
.directive('sonClick', function () {    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            element.bind('click',function(){       
                scope.$eval(attrs.sonClick);
            })
        }
    };
})
.controller('CtrlApp', function ($scope) {
    $scope.executa = function(){
        alert("scope");           
    };
});
```

**No html:**

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlApp">
    <button son-click="executa()">clique aqui</button>
</div>
```

**Modularização**

Esse é o mais simples e considero tão quanto os outros. Trata-se de separar em arquivos diferentes cada componente. Um arquivo para controlador, outro para serviço, outro para diretiva e assim por diante.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]